# how to print 2 or more random key from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
build_dic = {}
with open (filedictionary, 'r') as df:
    for kv in [d.strip().split(':') for d in df]:
        build_dic[kv[0]] = kv[1]

for key in build_dic:
    key = random.sample(build_dic, n)
    print key
```

and when i run it, it comes with

```
['to study', 'to talk', 'to make']
['to make', 'to run', 'to practice']
['to run', 'to talk', 'to take']
['to arrive', 'to practice', 'to suck']
['to run', 'to search', 'to practice']
['to arrive', 'to suck', 'to talk']
['to search', 'to like', 'to take']
['to take', 'to play', 'to study']
['to study', 'to take', 'to practice']
['to suck', 'to search', 'to run']
['to play', 'to suck', 'to make']
['to suck', 'to talk', 'to search']
```

what shall i do? I just want to 3 random keys from my dic.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop. You are looping over all the keys in the dictionary, and picking a new sample each iteration.

Just use `random.sample()` once:

```
n = 3
random_keys = random.sample(build_dic, n)
print random_keys
```

You can loop over the result of `random.sample()` of course.